# How to define a command to commit the n-th parent directory of the current one in Vim?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, vim

I have this shortcut in my `.vimrc` file:

```
map cmt :!start TortoiseProc.exe /command:commit /path:"%" /closeonend:3 <CR>
```

What this does is whenever I type `cmt`, Vim opens the commit dialog for the file I'm currently editing with Vim.

What I'd like to do is to write this command in such a way that if I put a number in front of it, it will open the commit dialog for the *n*-th level directory.

To give an example, let's say that I'm editing the `project/logs/access.log` file. Then,

- `cmt` should bring the dialog for committing `access.log`;
- `1cmt` should bring the dialog for committing the `logs` directory;
- `2cmt` should bring the dialog for committing the `project` directory;
  and so on.

Note: I'm using gVim on Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented the desired functionality in the following
function.

```
function! TortoiseCommitDialog(path, count)
    let pat = '[/\\]\@<=\%([^/\\]\+[/\\]\?\)\{' . a:count . '}$'
    let path = substitute(a:path, pat, '', '')
    let cmd = 'TortoiseProc.exe /command:commit ' .
    \   '/path:' . shellescape(path) . ' /closeonend:3'
    let out = system(cmd)
    if v:shell_error
        echoerr 'Failed to run Tortoise commit dialog'
        echo out
    end
endfunction
```

It takes two arguments: a path to the file to start from and a number
of levels to go up. Then it cuts the specified number of tailing path
components and builds the command to run (according to your example).
Then it runs the command and checks its exit code returned by the
shell after execution. If an error is occurred, an error message is
shown followed by the output of the command.

To use this function during editing, I recommend to define a command (because, unlike a mapping, it can take arguments):

```
command! -count Cmt call TortoiseCommitDialog(expand('%:p'), <count>)
```

Because of the `-count` flag you can run the command with a count in
two ways: both `:3Cmt` and `:Cmt 3` (or even `:Cmt3`) have the same
effect.